# create-react-app my-app ...command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, macos, reactjs, npm

I ran `npm install -g create-react-app` and everything seemed install correctly.

I then run `create-react-app my-app` and in return get `-bash: create-react-app: command not found`

I then tried changing my `./bash_profile $PATH` but yet I still get the error.

The location of all my packages is `Macintosh HD/Users/my_name/npm/bin`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

OSX 10.13 Beta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open your current bash file: 
   In Terminal, type: open ~/.bash_profile
   This will open the bash file in Text Editor

   But if you don't have a bash file, create a new one with

   touch ~/.bash_profile
2. Add this in the file:

   export PATH=$PATH:/Users/my_name/.npm-packages/bin
   *be sure to change my_name to your username
3. Restart Terminal
4. In Terminal, run

   create-react-app my-app

Comment: Joe, please accept the answer if it worked for you. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have given enough permission for the file path /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Then try this:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

After this you can create react app like

```
create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/my_name/.npm-packages/bin/
```

Comment: I'm still getting that error even after pasting those export changes into my ./bash_profile.

Answer (score 0):

Try running (use path to .\bin under node modules) for ex.
node_modules.bin\create-react-app my app. The reason for this being create-react-app is not on the PATH.